# SvelteKit breaks npm's import mechanism

Tags: npm, svelte, sveltekit

I've written several npm library projects, and this is the way I import symbols in one JS file from another JS file, but it won't work in the script section of a svelte file:
My 'package.json' file has a name field (e.g. set to '@jdeighan/something`) and an 'exports' section with entries like "./utils": "./src/lib/utils.js". Then in any other JS file I can import symbols from utils.js with "import {somesymbol} from '@jdeighan/something/utils'. It's how to do imports from a library that you've installed with 'npm install', but it also (cleverly) works inside the project itself. But in a svelte file, this won't work - I get the error message "Failed to resolve import "@jdeighan/something/utils" from "src\routes+page.svelte". Does the file exist?". Here is what I have in my svelte file:

```
<script>
import {somesymbol} from '@jdeighan/something/utils';
</script>
```

I know that svelte has a handy `$lib` alias, but I'd prefer to use the npm standard mechanism, but it seems to be broken when using SvelteKit (not sure about using plain svelte)

Comment: That should work just fine. Did you install the dependency? Does the import work from JS files in the same SvelteKit project?

Comment: If I change the import statement to 'import {somesymbol} from '$lib/utils.js';' then everything works fine. I have the usual setup where the project folder has a 'src' folder, which itself has a 'lib' folder. The utils.js file is in that lib folder. I haven't tried importing from one JS file to another and while that might provide some useful information, the issue is importing from a svelte file.

Comment: Let’s first confirm this is actually a sveltekit problem. Create a `foo.mjs` file in your project root containing `import {somesymbol} from '@jdeighan/something/utils'` and run `node foo.mjs`. If it doesn’t work with vanilla node.js then your presumption is wrong.

Comment: I always use ES6 modules, so I've modified your suggestion a bit, namely my package.json file contains "type": "module" and my file is named "foo.js". I created a brand new project using "mkdir test; npm init" and the project contains only 3 files. Since I'm too restricted in formatting here, I'll post the file contents below. In any case, I've been using this mechanism, especially in my unit tests, for a long time. It works with vanilla node.js

Comment: The code below confirms that, in fact, it DOES work with vanilla node.js

Answer (score 2):

> I'd prefer to use the npm standard mechanism

This is absolutely not the standard mechanism. I have never seen people import from the current project *by package name*. While this is supported by Node itself, nothing else seems to support it, including e.g. the VS Code language server which will be unable to provide code navigation.

Using the name makes it less clear that the import is local and not a separate dependency and if the name were to be changed it would have to be adjusted everywhere.

I would recommend just *not* doing that. SvelteKit has `$lib` predefined as a default to provide essentially the same functionality in a convention-based way that actually works.

Comment: 1. I said "npm standard". npm is part of node, so maybe I should have said 'node standard'. In any case, I much prefer it, so you have your opinion and I have mine. svelte works and I love it, but it has a lot of hacks in it - by necessity. Hopefully, the standards will be improved to make these hacks unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a project with just these 3 files, then execute `node foo.js` in a console window, you get "Hello, World!":

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@jdeighan/something",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "exports": {
    "./utils": "./utils.js"
    }
}
```

foo.js:

```
import {message} from '@jdeighan/something/utils'

console.log(message);
```

utils.js

```
export let message = 'Hello, World!';
```